# ESP8266 turns off after some time

Tags: arduino, sleep, esp8266

I have a ESP8266 wifi module connected to an arduino uno. On the ESP8266 I set up a socket server witch is working fine. And I can communicate with it as I expect.

After having run the ESP8266 some time (like 5-10 minutes) it automatically turns off (or goes into some kind of sleep mode. The LED turns off). I then have to re power the whole thing and reset it using the reset pin.

Why is my ESP8266 turning off and disconnecting from the WIFI?

Comment: Are you powering the module seperatly (not from the Arduino)? With a proper power supply (meaning it can deliver the required amps)?

Comment: No, I am powering it with the arduino. It Works if I have the usb plugged in together with the dc supply, but if I remove the usb, the esp8266 turns of after a few minutes...

Comment: Try to power it seperatly with a power supply that can deliver up to 1A and have a commun ground with the Arduino.

Comment: Maximum current draw from this voltage regulator on the Arduino Uno is 50 mA. You surely need better power supply.

Comment: @Defozo do you know what the maximum current draw from the 5v pin is? If it is enough, I can just put another, better power regulator on that pin.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I don't want to mislead you but AFAIK max current of 5v pin depends on max current draw of your Arduino's power supply and please remember that your standard USB's max current draw is 500 mA.

Comment: Yes, my maximum current draw of my power supply is 3.5A since I am also powering some dc motors. Now i just put a voltage regulator on the vin pin, and it Works perfectly! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum current draw from this voltage regulator on the Arduino Uno is 50 mA. It's surely not enough for ESP8266.

You need a power supply with at least 700 mA to make sure it works properly (ESP8266 usually takes about 60 mA but according to my experience the current draw can be very high during the startup).

Comment: Sure, I will try that. But the strange thing is that when I have the usb plugged in to the arduino, the esp8266 does not die, and I can run it for as long as i want...